# Extracting data from json_decode with lat and lng geolocation

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get the lat and lng values from a simple GET request and decode the JSON results, but there seems to be no data in the updated rows.

When I insert an IP address into the URL I can see that there is a valid lat and lng values, see below.

JSON example:

```
{
    "country_name": "DENMARK",
    "country_code": "DK",
    "city": "Havdrup",
    "ip": "xx",
    "lat": "55.4333",
    "lng": "9.25"
}
```

Code:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php?ip={$ip}&position=true"));

$lat = $details->lat;
$lng = $details->lng;

$result_update_settings = mysqli_query(
    $con,
    "UPDATE users SET
        lat = '" . $lat . "',
        lng = '" . $lng . "'
    WHERE id = '" . $login_session . "'"
) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Comment: show us your json array result to see json array

Comment: @ntaloventi its updated with json

Comment: try $lat = $details['lat']; $lng = $details['lng']; show the result

Comment: @ntaloventi without the second parameter, `json_decode()` will return an object, so the existing code is fine.

Comment: I also see that, just other ways to try

Comment: i have tried $lat = $details['lat']; $lng = $details['lng']; and then setting the json_decode ($, true) but it didnt work either. :/

Comment: First make sure you're getting the data, so try this: `$data = file_get_contents("http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php?ip={$ip}&position=true"); print_r($data);` and let us know what comes up.

Comment: i get: 
  {"country_name":"DENMARK","country_code":"DK","city":"Havdrup","ip":"90.185.152.241","lat":"55.4333","lng":"9.25"}

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by stating this, you should turn your error reporting on to pick up any potential issues that may arise. This can be done via adding the following to the top of your script:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Try not to simplify your `file_get_contents()` call yet. First ensure everything is working as it should:

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php?ip={$ip}&position=true");

$data = json_decode($json);
// you could print_r($data); here to see if you get what you requested.
$lat = $data->lat;
$lng = $data->lng;
// now echo, just to check if you actually get your values!
echo $lat . " & " . $lng;
```

Are you sure your query is successfully executing?

- What does `var_dump($result_update_settings);` after your query return?
- What is `$login_session`?